# How to create scrollable dialog box with fixed height in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I requesting some data using jquery ajax function.i have to display requested data in jquery scrollable dialog how can i do that.
Here i am using code.for requesting data.

```
$('#load').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "push/push_notify.php",
            data: "pushmessage="+message+"&iphone="+iphone+"&android="+android+"&blackberry="+blackberry,

            success: function(e){
                $('#load').hide();
                var response =e;

               $("#showtable").fadeOut('slow').load("alerttable.php").fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
       return false;
```

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'scrollable' - do you want a dialog of a fixed height with a scroll bar or what?

Comment: yes i want dialog box with fixed height and scroll bar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a dialog from [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and the container `div` element should have a fixed width & height and overflow set to `scroll` (scrollbars always appear) or `auto` (scrollbars appear when needed) .

CSS of the div:

```
#result-dialog{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto; /* Or scroll, depending on your needs*/
    width: 300px;
}
```

EDIT: [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaRE/134/) a working example of a [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) with scrollable content. For more properties and styles of the dialogbox you should check out its [page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

In your html you should include:

[jQuery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js), [jQuery UI](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js), and [jQuery UI CSS](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css) (these are hotlinks from Google's CDN - if you wish you can download these for yourself from jquery's home page)

Comment: Updated the answer, included [fully working example](http://jsfiddle.net/AvaRE/11/) jQuery, jQuery UI and CSS.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Are you want this css property ?

[Scrollable div](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow)

you must set the overflow and height width of the specific div